# resize rigify controller?

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, rigify

i use rigify many time but know i have a problem when i generate the rigify to my character the controls are too small and some of them are inside of him, i think its because the cartoon body of the character

so did anyone know how can i resize the rigify controller??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change *custom bone shapes* size and other attributes going to the *last layer*. Just select the desired shape there and adjust it in *Edit Mode*. 
[image]